# PHP ошибка Fatal Error. Как решить проблему?

Tags: php

Взял хостинг самый дешевый на unihost.com, залил онлайн игру - все работало с 128МБ ОЗУ. Затем при обращении к php файлу, который отвечает за связь с БД MySQL получил ошибку:

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes) in /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQL.php on line 2986** (Сегодня перешел на хостинг с 256МБ, не помогло ;-( )

Как решить проблему? Стоит ли переходить на хостинг с 384МБ ОЗУ?

Вот функция в которой происходит ошибка:

```
function mysql_fetch_all($result) {
        $all = array();
        if($result) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // 2986 строка
                $all[] = $row;
            }
            return $all;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А может стоит глянуть что за запрос такой и его оптимизировать? сомневаюсь что там нужно столько данных, что 256МБ ОЗУ не хватает. А если у Вас пара сотен человек обратится к скрипту?

Comment: Ну у тебя похоже while по какой-то причине не заканчивается. И всё это выходит за рамки дозволинной памяти.

Comment: Денис, While тут может не закончится только если результат выборки запроса бесконечный )) просто данных очень много и все они собираются в массив, который сжирает ОЗУ. Вот я и предложил автору посмотреть, может у него выводится миллион пользователей на страницу. Так можно тогда постранично разбить. Или может запрос SELECT * FROM news; а в таблицу выводит заголовки одни. Поэтому считаю правильно сначала посмотреть на запрос и понять, реально ли он необходим в таком виде, в каком он есть.

Comment: @Денис Евра, while тут может только по одной причине быть долгим( но не бесконечным! ): если количество затронутых записей слишком большое.

Comment: @eprivalov1 Покажите структуру таблицы с типом данных полей и какое количество записей у вас фетчится

Comment: Структуру показать не могу, но в таблице пока 3 миллиона записей и они постоянно добавляются...

Comment: А зачем все 3 миллиона вытягивать, неужели без этого никак?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как несложно догадаться, веб приложение расходует всю память, доступную на виртуальном сервере. Посмотрев на приведенный вами код, становится ясно, что ошибка происходит при попытке перенести результат запроса к таблице БД в оперативную память на сервере. Очевидно, выборка задевает огромное количество записей( суммарный объем информации в которых = 268435456/1024/1024  = 256МБ !! ). Есть несколько выходов: ограничивать количество затрагиваемых запросом записей из таблицы`( LIMIT, WHERE и т.д )` или же завести сервер с большим запасом ОЗУ. Предпочтительнее первый вариант, т.к в будущем вы обезопасите себя от  возникновения подобной проблемы. Да и вообще, нужно следить за подобными вещами..

Здесь вот, к примеру, один только номер строки пугает:

```
<b>Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43 bytes) in /var/www/user/data/www/site.ru/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQL.php on line 2986</b>
```

Такие гигантские скрипты следует разбивать на несколько файлов, чтобы хотя бы самому в нем потом не запутаться..

Comment: @0xFFh согласен на счет огромного кол-ва записей, а вот на счет ограничения не совсем, т.к. придется все равно склеивать если нужно все строки из таблицы фетчить

Comment: @Артёмыч, нет не придется. А точнее сказать, вероятно, не придется, так как никто из отвечающих не видел самого запроса и, следовательно, не знает его сути.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте добавить в самое начала **index.php** (расположенного в корне сайта) вот такую строчку. Память соответственно указать для своих целей.

```
<?php ini_set("memory_limit", "512M"); ?>
```

Или положить в корень сайта файл **.htaccess** следующего содержания:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

*Если это не помогло — обратитесь к администратору хостинга и попросите увеличить количество доступной памяти для PHP*

Попробуйте использовать функцию `mysql_fetch_row()` вместо `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Смысл? Если на сервере всего доступно лишь 128мб..

Comment: @0xFFh ...смысл есть всегда :)

Comment: @Артёмыч, глупый ответ. Как правило, лишние 200-300мб для хостинга обходятся в 2 раза дороже самого хостинга..нельзя вот так просто взять и одной строчкой добавить оперативки к хостингу :)

Comment: @AseN, а файла подкачки на хостингах нет?

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка означает, что ваш скрипт для выполнения требует памяти больше, чем разрешено в настройках PHP. Т.е. запрашиваемое значение превышает максимальное количество оперативной памяти предоставляемого пользовательскому аккаунту виртуальным хостингом. На разных хостингах это значение может отличаться.

Если у вас возникает такая проблема, то можно сделать следующее:

1. Попробовать самостоятельно изменить это значение, добавив в самое начало `index.php` (расположенного в корне сайта) следующие строчки:

   ```
   <?php ini_set("memory_limit", "512M"); ?>
   ```

   или же положив в корень сайта файл `.htaccess следующего содержания:

   ```
   php_value memory_limit 512M
   ```

   Если же такой файл уже есть в корне сайта — просто добавьте в него вышеприведенную строку.
2. Если это не помогло — обратитесь к администратору хостинга и попросите увеличить количество доступной памяти для PHP.

Comment: Автору не хватает 256, а Вы предлагаете ему 32 сделать лимит )

Comment: я прекрасно это понимаю, поэтому свое решение написал в комментарии вверху и считаю его на начальном этапе единственно верным.

Comment: исправил. Совет автору вопроса- попробуйте запустить локально(тот же Denwer) изменяя лимит памяти чтобы выяснить сколько ресурсов требуется для нормальной работы игры.